# Disable logging for springframework

Tags: java, spring

I have an **issue with logging** for [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/). I have `log4j.properties` file which works fine, the only thing I wanted to do is to disable `Spring Framework` logging. Thus, I added the following line, but seems that it does not work:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF
```

Otherwise if I set debug level for the whole project it works just fine. Where is the problem?

```
...
log4j.appender.my_log.append=true
log4j.appender.my_log.bufferSize=8192
log4j.appender.my_log.bufferedIO=false
...

log4j.appender.my_log.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.my_log.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.my_log.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%C{1}] - %m%n
log4j.logger.com.dummy.mydummybox=DEBUG, my_log
log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF, my_log
```

Comment: "to log some data" it's unclear to me

Comment: I just do not want springframework to log anything in a particular class.

Comment: Are you even using log4j (and log4j2 doesn't count as log4j!). Is the properties file in the correct location.

Comment: When I change this line log4j.logger.com.dummy.mydummybox=DEBUG, my_log loggins is correct, according to debug or info mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the solution was to disable logging for my class, which was extending the spring class.

i.e.

```
log4j.logger.com.my.dummy.class=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you question is not clear to me but still add following things might help you.

**log4j.logger.(packagename) = OFF**

Comment: I just want to disable logging in springframework for particular class. But even log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF did not help

Comment: what is your package name?

Comment: AbstractUrlHandlerMapping

Comment: Just edited answer please try like this and let me know

Comment: Tried log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping=OFF, but no changes. I have updated my description too

Comment: is it possible that it is somehow overridden or some inheritance issues?